# How can I compare column A in one row with column B in another, within groups?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of payment info for stock issues, where the relevant columns are:

- ID number (pk)
- Person number (fk to table of people)
- Issue number (fk to table of stock issues)
- Start date
- End date

So if person #100 has holdings in issue #25 and they get a payment on 1/1/2019, then the table is checked for the date, issue, and person to determine where to send the payment.

For a single person and issue, there can be multiple sets of payment information if it changes. The problem is that in some cases, for person #100 under issue #25, the end date for one range is the same as the start date for the next range when they should be consecutive. For example:

```
Record 1: 01/01/2019 to 03/01/2019  
Record 2: 03/01/2019 to 06/01/2019
```

instead of

```
Record 1: 01/01/2019 to 02/28/2019  
Record 2: 03/01/2019 to 06/01/2019
```

How can I search through, and within each group of person/issue pairs check if there are any overlaps in start and end dates? I have a pretty good handle on vanilla SQL but a tenuous grasp on PL/SQL which seems to be necessary in this case. Because it's such a specific and difficult-to-describe scenario, I'm having some trouble finding the right help on Google.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Produce a report? Disallow overlaps when adding new data? Please clarify your question.

Comment: I'm trying to select a list of all records whose end date is the same as another starting date with the same pair of person and issue IDs. Apologies for not making that clear.

Answer (score 0):

input:

```
insert into payment (id, startdate, enddate) values (1,'13/01/2019','20/01/2019');
insert into payment (id, startdate, enddate) values (2,'21/01/2019','30/01/2019');
insert into payment (id, startdate, enddate) values (3,'30/01/2019','02/02/2019');
insert into payment (id, startdate, enddate) values (4,'30/01/2019','02/02/2019');
```

Too vanilla ?

```
select p1.id, p2.id
from payment p1
  inner join payment p2 on p2.id <> p1.id 
        and p2.startdate between  p1.startdate and p1.enddate
```

output:

```
2   3
2   4
3   4
4   3
```

or

```
select p1.*
  from payment p1
 where exists (select 1 
                 from payment p2 
                where p2.id <> p1.id 
                  and  p2.startdate between p1.startdate and p1.enddate)
```

output:

```
2
3
4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generically check for overlaps, you can do:

```
select p.*
from payments p
where exists (select 1
              from payments p2
              where p2.person_id = p.person_id and
                    p2.stock = p.stock and
                    p2.enddate >= p.startdate and
                    p2.startdate <= p.enddate
             )
order by p.person_id, p.stock, p.startdate;
```

This finds *all* overlaps including nested ones:

```
---A-------B-----B------A----
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
select * from payment p1 
where end_date in 
    (select p2.start_date 
        from payment p2 
        where p2.person_number = p1.person_number );
```

This way you will get all person records that have the same end date as start date for diff issues.